# Getting data from HTML into React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My backend server is rendering an HTML page with some data in a javascript object as well as the root element that the React/Redux app uses:

```
<script>
MY_DATA = {
    foo: 'bar'
}
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

I need to somehow get this `MY_DATA` from the HTML into my redux store.  I tried using my React root element's componentDidMount to pull the data from the window object, but that didn't work.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grab the initial state from window and pass it to your createStore. It's explained [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html) (client side section)

```
const initialState = window.MY_DATA

// Create Redux store with initial state
const store = createStore(yourApp, initialState)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```